# React highcharts not showing plotlines

Tags: reactjs, highcharts

I having trouble on displaying multiline chart in highcharts because the plotlines are not displaying. but, i have 2 sample json, 1 from a dummy data which is displaying properly but the other json is from my server with the same keys and properties just different values in it and it does not show the plotlines but the plotbands is displaying.

here is my dummy json (that is displaying properly):

```
[{"marker_id":73,"marker_name":"A","name":"A","data":[{"x":1541725260000,"y":60.2,"data_id":210766,"mo_id":54050},{"x":1542332940000,"y":60,"data_id":211166,"mo_id":54153},{"x":1542672720000,"y":60,"data_id":211235,"mo_id":54175},{"x":1543274520000,"y":60,"data_id":211536,"mo_id":54248},{"x":1543536300000,"y":60,"data_id":211626,"mo_id":54267},{"x":1543884900000,"y":60,"data_id":211692,"mo_id":54283},{"x":1544149920000,"y":60,"data_id":211799,"mo_id":54306},{"x":1544498580000,"y":60,"data_id":211857,"mo_id":54321},{"x":1544748120000,"y":60,"data_id":211896,"mo_id":54334},{"x":1545353040000,"y":60,"data_id":212135,"mo_id":54391},{"x":1545699720000,"y":60,"data_id":212297,"mo_id":54440},{"x":1545952680000,"y":60,"data_id":212373,"mo_id":54458},{"x":1546313160000,"y":60,"data_id":212616,"mo_id":54530},{"x":1546906860000,"y":60,"data_id":212892,"mo_id":54604}]},{"marker_id":197,"marker_name":"B","name":"B","data":[{"x":1541725260000,"y":58,"data_id":210768,"mo_id":54050},{"x":1542332940000,"y":58,"data_id":211168,"mo_id":54153},{"x":1542672720000,"y":58,"data_id":211237,"mo_id":54175},{"x":1543274520000,"y":58,"data_id":211538,"mo_id":54248},{"x":1543536300000,"y":58,"data_id":211628,"mo_id":54267},{"x":1543884900000,"y":58,"data_id":211694,"mo_id":54283},{"x":1544149920000,"y":58,"data_id":211801,"mo_id":54306},{"x":1544498580000,"y":58,"data_id":211859,"mo_id":54321},{"x":1544748120000,"y":58,"data_id":211898,"mo_id":54334},{"x":1545353040000,"y":58,"data_id":212137,"mo_id":54391},{"x":1545699720000,"y":58,"data_id":212299,"mo_id":54440},{"x":1545952680000,"y":58,"data_id":212375,"mo_id":54458},{"x":1546313160000,"y":58,"data_id":212618,"mo_id":54530},{"x":1546906860000,"y":58,"data_id":212894,"mo_id":54604}]},{"marker_id":196,"marker_name":"C","name":"C","data":[{"x":1541725260000,"y":75,"data_id":210767,"mo_id":54050},{"x":1542332940000,"y":75,"data_id":211167,"mo_id":54153},{"x":1542672720000,"y":75,"data_id":211236,"mo_id":54175},{"x":1543274520000,"y":75,"data_id":211537,"mo_id":54248},{"x":1543536300000,"y":75,"data_id":211627,"mo_id":54267},{"x":1543884900000,"y":75,"data_id":211693,"mo_id":54283},{"x":1544149920000,"y":75,"data_id":211800,"mo_id":54306},{"x":1544498580000,"y":75,"data_id":211858,"mo_id":54321},{"x":1544748120000,"y":75,"data_id":211897,"mo_id":54334},{"x":1545353040000,"y":75,"data_id":212136,"mo_id":54391},{"x":1545699720000,"y":75,"data_id":212298,"mo_id":54440},{"x":1545952680000,"y":75,"data_id":212374,"mo_id":54458},{"x":1546313160000,"y":75,"data_id":212617,"mo_id":54530}]},{"marker_id":199,"marker_name":"D","name":"D","data":[{"x":1541725260000,"y":50,"data_id":210770,"mo_id":54050},{"x":1542332940000,"y":50,"data_id":211170,"mo_id":54153},{"x":1542672720000,"y":50,"data_id":211239,"mo_id":54175},{"x":1543274520000,"y":50,"data_id":211540,"mo_id":54248},{"x":1543536300000,"y":50,"data_id":211630,"mo_id":54267},{"x":1543884900000,"y":50,"data_id":211696,"mo_id":54283},{"x":1544149920000,"y":50,"data_id":211803,"mo_id":54306},{"x":1544498580000,"y":50,"data_id":211861,"mo_id":54321},{"x":1544748120000,"y":50,"data_id":211900,"mo_id":54334},{"x":1545353040000,"y":50,"data_id":212139,"mo_id":54391},{"x":1545699720000,"y":50,"data_id":212301,"mo_id":54440},{"x":1545952680000,"y":50,"data_id":212377,"mo_id":54458},{"x":1546313160000,"y":50,"data_id":212620,"mo_id":54530},{"x":1546906860000,"y":50,"data_id":212896,"mo_id":54604}]},{"marker_id":198,"marker_name":"E","name":"E","data":[{"x":1541725260000,"y":59,"data_id":210769,"mo_id":54050},{"x":1542332940000,"y":59,"data_id":211169,"mo_id":54153},{"x":1542672720000,"y":59,"data_id":211238,"mo_id":54175},{"x":1543274520000,"y":59,"data_id":211539,"mo_id":54248},{"x":1543536300000,"y":59,"data_id":211629,"mo_id":54267},{"x":1543884900000,"y":59,"data_id":211695,"mo_id":54283},{"x":1544149920000,"y":59,"data_id":211802,"mo_id":54306},{"x":1544498580000,"y":59,"data_id":211860,"mo_id":54321},{"x":1544748120000,"y":59,"data_id":211899,"mo_id":54334},{"x":1545353040000,"y":59,"data_id":212138,"mo_id":54391},{"x":1545699720000,"y":59,"data_id":212300,"mo_id":54440},{"x":1545952680000,"y":59,"data_id":212376,"mo_id":54458},{"x":1546313160000,"y":59,"data_id":212619,"mo_id":54530},{"x":1546906860000,"y":59,"data_id":212895,"mo_id":54604}]},{"marker_id":201,"marker_name":"F","name":"F","data":[{"x":1541725260000,"y":48,"data_id":210771,"mo_id":54050},{"x":1542332940000,"y":48,"data_id":211171,"mo_id":54153},{"x":1542672720000,"y":48,"data_id":211240,"mo_id":54175},{"x":1543274520000,"y":48,"data_id":211541,"mo_id":54248},{"x":1543536300000,"y":48,"data_id":211631,"mo_id":54267},{"x":1543884900000,"y":48,"data_id":211697,"mo_id":54283},{"x":1544149920000,"y":48,"data_id":211804,"mo_id":54306},{"x":1544498580000,"y":48,"data_id":211862,"mo_id":54321},{"x":1544748120000,"y":48,"data_id":211901,"mo_id":54334},{"x":1545353040000,"y":48,"data_id":212140,"mo_id":54391},{"x":1545699720000,"y":48,"data_id":212302,"mo_id":54440},{"x":1545952680000,"y":48,"data_id":212378,"mo_id":54458},{"x":1546313160000,"y":48,"data_id":212621,"mo_id":54530},{"x":1546906860000,"y":48,"data_id":212897,"mo_id":54604}]}]
```

and this is the real json i want to plot:

```
[{"data":[{"data_id":224524,"mo_id":57288,"x":1567479600,"y":72.1},{"data_id":224622,"mo_id":57311,"x":1567738800,"y":72.7},{"data_id":224777,"mo_id":57344,"x":1568084400,"y":72.8},{"data_id":224980,"mo_id":57386,"x":1568343600,"y":72.8},{"data_id":225095,"mo_id":57413,"x":1568687700,"y":72.7},{"data_id":225105,"mo_id":57415,"x":1568689200,"y":72.7},{"data_id":225271,"mo_id":57450,"x":1568950200,"y":72.7},{"data_id":225371,"mo_id":57475,"x":1569295800,"y":72.8},{"data_id":225485,"mo_id":57501,"x":1569555000,"y":72.6},{"data_id":225559,"mo_id":57519,"x":1569909600,"y":72.8},{"data_id":225817,"mo_id":57579,"x":1570159800,"y":72.8},{"data_id":226660,"mo_id":57770,"x":1570410900,"y":72.7},{"data_id":225877,"mo_id":57593,"x":1570503600,"y":72.8},{"data_id":225957,"mo_id":57612,"x":1570762800,"y":72.9},{"data_id":226040,"mo_id":57634,"x":1571108400,"y":72.9},{"data_id":226154,"mo_id":57658,"x":1571367600,"y":72.8},{"data_id":226229,"mo_id":57675,"x":1571713200,"y":72.9},{"data_id":226327,"mo_id":57697,"x":1571972400,"y":72.9},{"data_id":226424,"mo_id":57719,"x":1572319800,"y":72.8},{"data_id":226549,"mo_id":57745,"x":1572579000,"y":72.8},{"data_id":226649,"mo_id":57768,"x":1573011000,"y":72.7},{"data_id":226664,"mo_id":57771,"x":1573088400,"y":72.7},{"data_id":226668,"mo_id":57772,"x":1573089300,"y":72.7},{"data_id":226672,"mo_id":57773,"x":1573096500,"y":72.7},{"data_id":226683,"mo_id":57775,"x":1573110900,"y":72.7},{"data_id":226694,"mo_id":57777,"x":1573167600,"y":72.7},{"data_id":226736,"mo_id":57788,"x":1573182900,"y":72.8},{"data_id":226760,"mo_id":57793,"x":1573197000,"y":72.7},{"data_id":226764,"mo_id":57794,"x":1573254000,"y":72.9},{"data_id":226782,"mo_id":57797,"x":1573269300,"y":72.9},{"data_id":226805,"mo_id":57802,"x":1573282800,"y":72.9},{"data_id":226855,"mo_id":57810,"x":1573354800,"y":72.9},{"data_id":226941,"mo_id":57828,"x":1573527600,"y":72.7},{"data_id":227545,"mo_id":57970,"x":1575427800,"y":72.8},{"data_id":227768,"mo_id":58032,"x":1576031400,"y":72.9},{"data_id":228011,"mo_id":58086,"x":1576638000,"y":72.8}],"marker_id":90,"marker_name":"A","name":"A"},{"data":[{"data_id":224526,"mo_id":57288,"x":1567479600,"y":80.4},{"data_id":224624,"mo_id":57311,"x":1567738800,"y":80.6},{"data_id":224779,"mo_id":57344,"x":1568084400,"y":80.6},{"data_id":224982,"mo_id":57386,"x":1568343600,"y":80.7},{"data_id":225097,"mo_id":57413,"x":1568687700,"y":80.5},{"data_id":225107,"mo_id":57415,"x":1568689200,"y":80.5},{"data_id":225273,"mo_id":57450,"x":1568950200,"y":80.6},{"data_id":225373,"mo_id":57475,"x":1569295800,"y":80.6},{"data_id":225487,"mo_id":57501,"x":1569555000,"y":80.9},{"data_id":225561,"mo_id":57519,"x":1569909600,"y":80.7},{"data_id":225819,"mo_id":57579,"x":1570159800,"y":80.7},{"data_id":226662,"mo_id":57770,"x":1570410900,"y":80.8},{"data_id":225879,"mo_id":57593,"x":1570503600,"y":80.7},{"data_id":225959,"mo_id":57612,"x":1570762800,"y":80.7},{"data_id":226042,"mo_id":57634,"x":1571108400,"y":80.8},{"data_id":226156,"mo_id":57658,"x":1571367600,"y":80.8},{"data_id":226231,"mo_id":57675,"x":1571713200,"y":80.9},{"data_id":226329,"mo_id":57697,"x":1571972400,"y":80.8},{"data_id":226426,"mo_id":57719,"x":1572319800,"y":80.5},{"data_id":226551,"mo_id":57745,"x":1572579000,"y":80.8},{"data_id":226651,"mo_id":57768,"x":1573011000,"y":80.9},{"data_id":226666,"mo_id":57771,"x":1573088400,"y":80.8},{"data_id":226670,"mo_id":57772,"x":1573089300,"y":80.8},{"data_id":226674,"mo_id":57773,"x":1573096500,"y":80.8},{"data_id":226685,"mo_id":57775,"x":1573110900,"y":80.7},{"data_id":226696,"mo_id":57777,"x":1573167600,"y":80.8},{"data_id":226738,"mo_id":57788,"x":1573182900,"y":80.7},{"data_id":226762,"mo_id":57793,"x":1573197000,"y":80.7},{"data_id":226766,"mo_id":57794,"x":1573254000,"y":80.7},{"data_id":226784,"mo_id":57797,"x":1573269300,"y":80.7},{"data_id":226807,"mo_id":57802,"x":1573282800,"y":80.7},{"data_id":226857,"mo_id":57810,"x":1573354800,"y":80.7},{"data_id":226943,"mo_id":57828,"x":1573527600,"y":80.8},{"data_id":227547,"mo_id":57970,"x":1575427800,"y":80.8},{"data_id":227770,"mo_id":58032,"x":1576031400,"y":80.8},{"data_id":228013,"mo_id":58086,"x":1576638000,"y":80.8}],"marker_id":92,"marker_name":"B","name":"B"},{"data":[{"data_id":224525,"mo_id":57288,"x":1567479600,"y":81},{"data_id":224623,"mo_id":57311,"x":1567738800,"y":80.5},{"data_id":224778,"mo_id":57344,"x":1568084400,"y":80.5},{"data_id":224981,"mo_id":57386,"x":1568343600,"y":80.6},{"data_id":225096,"mo_id":57413,"x":1568687700,"y":81.5},{"data_id":225106,"mo_id":57415,"x":1568689200,"y":81.5},{"data_id":225272,"mo_id":57450,"x":1568950200,"y":81.7},{"data_id":225372,"mo_id":57475,"x":1569295800,"y":81.5},{"data_id":225486,"mo_id":57501,"x":1569555000,"y":81.5},{"data_id":225560,"mo_id":57519,"x":1569909600,"y":81.6},{"data_id":225818,"mo_id":57579,"x":1570159800,"y":81.6},{"data_id":226661,"mo_id":57770,"x":1570410900,"y":81.5},{"data_id":225878,"mo_id":57593,"x":1570503600,"y":81.5},{"data_id":225958,"mo_id":57612,"x":1570762800,"y":81.5},{"data_id":226041,"mo_id":57634,"x":1571108400,"y":81.6},{"data_id":226155,"mo_id":57658,"x":1571367600,"y":81.6},{"data_id":226230,"mo_id":57675,"x":1571713200,"y":81.8},{"data_id":226328,"mo_id":57697,"x":1571972400,"y":81.6},{"data_id":226425,"mo_id":57719,"x":1572319800,"y":81.5},{"data_id":226550,"mo_id":57745,"x":1572579000,"y":81.5},{"data_id":226650,"mo_id":57768,"x":1573011000,"y":81.7},{"data_id":226665,"mo_id":57771,"x":1573088400,"y":81.5},{"data_id":226669,"mo_id":57772,"x":1573089300,"y":81.5},{"data_id":226673,"mo_id":57773,"x":1573096500,"y":81.5},{"data_id":226684,"mo_id":57775,"x":1573110900,"y":81.5},{"data_id":226695,"mo_id":57777,"x":1573167600,"y":81.7},{"data_id":226737,"mo_id":57788,"x":1573182900,"y":81.8},{"data_id":226761,"mo_id":57793,"x":1573197000,"y":81.8},{"data_id":226765,"mo_id":57794,"x":1573254000,"y":81.8},{"data_id":226783,"mo_id":57797,"x":1573269300,"y":81.8},{"data_id":226806,"mo_id":57802,"x":1573282800,"y":81.8},{"data_id":226856,"mo_id":57810,"x":1573354800,"y":81.6},{"data_id":226942,"mo_id":57828,"x":1573527600,"y":81.7},{"data_id":227546,"mo_id":57970,"x":1575427800,"y":81.8},{"data_id":227769,"mo_id":58032,"x":1576031400,"y":81.8},{"data_id":228012,"mo_id":58086,"x":1576638000,"y":81.8}],"marker_id":91,"marker_name":"C","name":"C"},{"data":[{"data_id":224527,"mo_id":57288,"x":1567479600,"y":58.3},{"data_id":224625,"mo_id":57311,"x":1567738800,"y":58.3},{"data_id":224780,"mo_id":57344,"x":1568084400,"y":58},{"data_id":224983,"mo_id":57386,"x":1568343600,"y":58},{"data_id":225098,"mo_id":57413,"x":1568687700,"y":58},{"data_id":225108,"mo_id":57415,"x":1568689200,"y":58},{"data_id":225274,"mo_id":57450,"x":1568950200,"y":58},{"data_id":225374,"mo_id":57475,"x":1569295800,"y":58.8},{"data_id":225488,"mo_id":57501,"x":1569555000,"y":59.1},{"data_id":225562,"mo_id":57519,"x":1569909600,"y":58.7},{"data_id":225820,"mo_id":57579,"x":1570159800,"y":58.8},{"data_id":226663,"mo_id":57770,"x":1570410900,"y":58.9},{"data_id":225880,"mo_id":57593,"x":1570503600,"y":58.1},{"data_id":225960,"mo_id":57612,"x":1570762800,"y":59},{"data_id":226043,"mo_id":57634,"x":1571108400,"y":59},{"data_id":226157,"mo_id":57658,"x":1571367600,"y":58.7},{"data_id":226232,"mo_id":57675,"x":1571713200,"y":58.9},{"data_id":226330,"mo_id":57697,"x":1571972400,"y":59},{"data_id":226427,"mo_id":57719,"x":1572319800,"y":59},{"data_id":226552,"mo_id":57745,"x":1572579000,"y":58.9},{"data_id":226652,"mo_id":57768,"x":1573011000,"y":59},{"data_id":226667,"mo_id":57771,"x":1573088400,"y":58.9},{"data_id":226671,"mo_id":57772,"x":1573089300,"y":58.9},{"data_id":226675,"mo_id":57773,"x":1573096500,"y":58.9},{"data_id":226686,"mo_id":57775,"x":1573110900,"y":58.9},{"data_id":226697,"mo_id":57777,"x":1573167600,"y":59},{"data_id":226739,"mo_id":57788,"x":1573182900,"y":59},{"data_id":226763,"mo_id":57793,"x":1573197000,"y":59},{"data_id":226767,"mo_id":57794,"x":1573254000,"y":59},{"data_id":226785,"mo_id":57797,"x":1573269300,"y":59},{"data_id":226808,"mo_id":57802,"x":1573282800,"y":59},{"data_id":226858,"mo_id":57810,"x":1573354800,"y":59},{"data_id":226944,"mo_id":57828,"x":1573527600,"y":59},{"data_id":227548,"mo_id":57970,"x":1575427800,"y":59},{"data_id":227771,"mo_id":58032,"x":1576031400,"y":59},{"data_id":228014,"mo_id":58086,"x":1576638000,"y":58.9}],"marker_id":93,"marker_name":"D","name":"D"}]
```

even tho i set this json to a static variable just for verification, it still does not display the plotlines.

i wish u could help me with this issue.

Im using react highcharts from highcharts official repo.

Comment: Hi @John Geliberte, Your data seems to be displayed correctly: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/6m4e8x0y/4928/

Comment: Hello, that's what i thought too but the plotlines doesnt show whenever i try to plot it.

Comment: Plot lines are also displayed correctly, example: http://jsfiddle.net/qxgzsd5a/

Comment: Hello, uponwith  further testing i found the culprit. it is highcharts and momentjs not compatible each other.